# how can parametrized URL values using a registry key in FireFox and edge like chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge, chromium, mozilla

I want to install an extension via registry and also set install_parameter in it and read through manifest file as described in [chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/settings_override/#customizing). Can anyone know how to do same thing in firefox and edge?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs, you can distribute Edge extensions through the registry. But only for extensions that have been published in Edge Adds-on.

To distribute your extension using the Windows registry:

1. Find or create the following key in the registry:

   32-bit Windows: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions`.

   64-bit Windows: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions`.
2. Create a new key, or folder, under Extensions with the same name as the **ID** of your extension. Like this:
   [image]
3. In the Extensions key, create the `update_url` property, and set the value to `https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx`.

For more details, please refer to this doc: [Alternative ways to distribute extensions-Use the Windows registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/alternate-distribution-options#use-the-windows-registry-windows-only).